# How to handle the case like 10 calls in 1 sec and not more than 50 calls in 1 minute in rate limiter

Tags: java, spring-boot, security, spring-security

How to handle the case like 10 calls in 1 sec and not more than 50 calls in 1 minute in rate limiter in Spring.
I am making a spring rate limiter but can anyone tell me the ways I can do it please.

Answer (score -1):

If you are going to be running your Spring-Boot based API on a single server then look into Guava Ratelimiter. You can find instructions on how to implement the Guava Ratelimiter here: https://www.baeldung.com/guava-rate-limiter